# На консоли появляются лишние символы, fstream, C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, fstream

У меня есть код:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int numArr = 100;
    char text[numArr];

    ifstream file("text.txt");
    file.getline(text, numArr);
    file.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < numArr; i++)
        cout << text[i];

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

В документе text.txt написано:

```
Один, два, три
```

Почему, когда я запускаю программу, то у меня в консоли появляются лишние символы (в данном случаем буква Mm)?

```
Один, два, три ММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММДля продолжения нажмите любую клавишу...
```

Comment: Ну так что ж им не появляться-то? В файле 14 символов, а буфер у вас размера 100. В файле не хватает символов, чтобы заполнить весь буфер. А вы безусловно печатаете весь буфер (все 100 символов), т.е. мусор содержащийся в лишних символах буфера. Чего вы ожидали-то? Что по вашему должно печататься для незаполненной части буфера?

Comment: Другой символ, например

Comment: У вас ваш буфер изначально содержит непредсказуемый мусор. Этот мусор вы и видите. Если вы хотите видеть там "другой символ", то вам придется самому заполнить этот буфер этим "другим символом" (заранее или потом). Например, если перед чтением сделать `memset(text, '%', numArr);`, то буфер будет заполнен символом `%`. Но мне по-прежнему не ясно, зачем вы печатаете *весь* буфер (100 символов), когда из файла было прочитано только 14 символов. Просто ради эксперимента?

Comment: Спасибо!
Да, ради эксперимента. Я начинающий в C++

Comment: Еще вопрос, немного странный. У меня есть два массива. Возможно ли как-то все элементы первого массива перенести во второй, но в один элемент? То есть все элементы <code>int arro[] = {1, 2, 3};</code> перенести во второй так, чтобы был только один <code>int tarr[] = {123, 4, 5};</code>?